# How to center any number in element

Tags: html, css

So I have a circle that has a number in it that changes based off of user data. How would you make it so the number is centered at all times, regardless of which number it is?

```css
.Box {
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #9ba2a8;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 5px;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  bottom: 15px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-left: 40px
}

.TLP-blueBg {
  background-color: #2b88c7;
  transition: background-color 0.35s ease;
}

.Text {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 4px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -2.15px;
  font: 200 1.25em/1.3em 'Open Sans';
  color: white;
}

.task {
  width: 100%;
  height: 55px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: white;
  border-top: solid #eaeaea 1px;
  border-bottom: solid #eaeaea 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="Box">
  <p class="Text">1</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use transform, like this:

**CSS**

```
.Text {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top:50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50% , -50%);
  font: 200 1.25em/1.3em 'Open Sans';
  color: white;
  margin:0;
}
```

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/luispa/qb9mxkhy/40/)**

Comment: Great answer. Out of curiosity, how would you center it with these both in the circle? How would both be centered? https://jsfiddle.net/qb9mxkhy/43/

Comment: @Will simple, just change a few things in HTML and CSS - https://jsfiddle.net/luispa/qb9mxkhy/55/

Comment: If you consider browser compatibility,the property "transform" may not work under IE 9.

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of position property and also with other unnecessary css rule. Try this code.

```
.Text {
  display: inline-block;
  font: 200 1.25em/1.3em 'Open Sans';
  color: white;
  line-height: 35px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `position: absolute` from `.Text` class. Due to it, the text inside it was not getting aligned properly - as per what you want.

Here is the working example: https://jsfiddle.net/qb9mxkhy/33/

Check that this even works when you have 3 digits inside `.Text`

Answer (score 0):

Change your `.Text` CSS to this:

```
.Text{
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 4px;
    font: 200 1.25em/1.3em 'Open Sans';
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.Box {
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #9ba2a8;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 5px;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  bottom: 15px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-left: 40px
}

.Text {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 4px;
  left: 50%;
  font: 200 1.25em/1.3em 'Open Sans';
  color: white;
}

.task {
  width: 100%;
  height: 55px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: white;
  border-top: solid #eaeaea 1px;
  border-bottom: solid #eaeaea 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="Box">
  <p class="Text">4</p>
</div>
```

Remove the position: absolute; and margin-left: -2.15px; from .text class.

Answer (score 0):

In class text:

```
.Text {
     text-align: center;/*add this line*/
     vertical-align: middle;
     display: inline-block;
     margin-top: 4px;
     /*remove*/
     /*this*/position: absolute;
     /*this*/left: 50%;
     /*and this*/margin-left: -2.15px;
     font: 200 1.25em/1.3em 'Open Sans';
     color: white;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you the ***Flexbox*** way:

```css
.Box {
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #9ba2a8;
  margin-left: 5px;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  bottom: 15px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-left: 40px;
  
  display: flex; /* displays flex-items (children) inline */
  justify-content: center; /* centers them horizontally */
  align-items: center; /* and vertically */
}

.Text {
  font: 200 1.25em/1.3em 'Open Sans';
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="Box">
  <p class="Text">1</p>
</div>

<div class="Box">
  <p class="Text">99</p>
</div>

<div class="Box">
  <p class="Text">404</p>
</div>
```